# How to communicate real-time data between Java and C++ code?

Tags: java, c++, communication

My application includes 2 devices - a phone and a CPU. The phone is transferring data constantly to the laptop at low latencies (milliseconds). Both can be assumed to have Wifi.

What existing software should I look into for accomplishing this task? Any example applications I should look at?

Cheers

Comment: What kind of data? If it's something that can serialize into JSON, JSON-RPC works great (I have a lot of projects which use JSON-RPC for millisecond-latency interapp communication).

Comment: Could you provide a basic tutorial?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON-RPC#Implementations has a list of libraries that probably have tutorials. The specification is http://www.jsonrpc.org/specification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like RabbitMQ or ZeroMQ could be worth a look. I think you are looking for a messaging layer / protocol that provides a native client for both Java and C++, and that can handle (or let you handle in your client code) any serialisation issues correctly related to your platforms (endian-ness would be the primary issue to look at).